# Insert JSON into MySQL JSON column format using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, json, node.js

I have a Mysql table with these settings :

```
    CREATE TABLE `WorkOrders` (
  `workorder_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `intertype_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `equipment_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `reason_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `requester_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `workorder_creationdatetime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `phase_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `criticality_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `workorder_targetdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `workorder_enddatetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `workorder_content` json DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`workorder_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The column 'workorder_content' have a JSON datatype.

Then I have an AngularJS + Bootstrap linked to the database using a NodeJS api.

I am trying to insert data to my table using that script :

```
connection.acquire(function(err, con) {
      con.query('INSERT INTO WorkOrders SET ?', workorder.workorder.int, function(err, result) {
        con.release();
        console.log(err);
        if (err) {
          res.send({status: 1, message: 'WorkOrder creation failed'});
        } else {
          res.send({status: 0, message: 'WorkOrder created successfully'});
        }
      });
    });
```

And here is what workorder.workorder.int contains :

```
{ phase_id: 1,
  intertype_id: '14',
  reason_id: '1',
  equipment_id: '2',
  requester_id: '24',
  criticality_id: '29',
  workorder_content: 
   { adresse_client: 'sefsdf',
     type_machin: '1',
     type_truc: '8',
     truc_cocher: true,
     truc_radio: '11',
     date_debut: '12/07/2017' } }
```

The error I have in the NodeJS console is :
{ Error: UNKNOWN_CODE_PLEASE_REPORT: Invalid JSON text: "Invalid value." at position 1 in value (or column) '[object Object]'.

Can you please help me ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You're sending a string called '[object Object]'. to MySQL instead of the object. Try the following:

```
connection.acquire(function(err, con) {
      con.query('INSERT INTO WorkOrders SET ?', JSON.stringify(workorder.workorder.int), function(err, result) {
        con.release();
        console.log(err);
        if (err) {
          res.send({status: 1, message: 'WorkOrder creation failed'});
        } else {
          res.send({status: 0, message: 'WorkOrder created successfully'});
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: I am now having this in workorder.workorder.int : {"phase_id":1,"intertype_id":"14","reason_id":"1","equipment_id":"2","requester_id":"24","criticality_id":"29","workorder_content":{"adresse_client":"sefsdf","type_machin":"1","type_truc":"8","truc_cocher":true,"truc_radio":"11","date_debut":"12/07/2017"}} but i have this error : Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''{\"phase_id\":1,\"intertype_id\":\"14\",\"reason_id\":\"1\",\"equipment_id\":\"' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to sidewinder, I found the solution.

Here it is :

```
workorder.workorder.int.workorder_content = JSON.stringify(workorder.workorder.ext);

    connection.acquire(function(err, con) {
      con.query('INSERT INTO `WorkOrders` SET ?', workorder.workorder.int, function(err, result) {
        con.release();
        console.log(err);
        if (err) {
          res.send({status: 1, message: 'WorkOrder creation failed'});
        } else {
          res.send({status: 0, message: 'WorkOrder created successfully'});
        }
      });
    });
```

So it was needed to stringify the part that will be inserted to the JSON column in MySQL but not the entire JSON object.